# moment.locale adding extra day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I try to add `moment.locale` to my code:

```
    if(time_to_exe == 6)
    {
        moment.locale('fr', {
    months : 'janvier_février_mars_avril_mai_juin_juillet_août_septembre_octobre_novembre_décembre'.split('_')});
var orderDateTime = moment();
// Get Sunday (first day) of this week and add 3 days (to get to Wednesday) and set the time to 11:59am
var cutOffDate = moment().startOf('week').add(3,'days').set({'hour': 11, 'minute': 59, 'second': 59});
// Initialize delivery date from order date
var deliveryDate = orderDateTime.clone();
if (orderDateTime.isSameOrBefore(cutOffDate)) {
    deliveryDate = deliveryDate.add(1,'week').startOf('week').add(1,'day'); // Monday next week
} else {
    deliveryDate = deliveryDate.add(2,'week').startOf('week').add(1,'day'); // Monday the week after next
}
    
    if (deliveryDate) {
  time_to_exe = deliveryDate.format("D MMMM");
      
    } else {
      time_to_exe = time_to_exe + "d";
    }
    }
```

Everything working fine, textual month showing in French, but the problem is that `moment.locale` add an extra day

Example: before `moment.locale` my date show 6 September (in English), but after an added `moment.locale` it's showing 7 Septembre (in French)

Why it's adding an extra day?

Comment: Which time zone are you in?

Comment: @GabrielDonadelDall'Agnol Currently Eastern European Summer Time (EEST), UTC +3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment is old and it only adds a lot extra of weight to yow bundle.
JavaScript is capable to do more and better things by its own

```
const event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options));
// expected output: Donnerstag, 20. Dezember 2012

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('ar-EG', options));
// expected output: الخميس، ٢٠ ديسمبر، ٢٠١٢

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options));
// expected output: Thursday, December 20, 2012 (varies according to default locale)
```

Learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by myself, just remove .add(1,'day')
As I understand, then before a week started with the Sunday, and the needed to add 1 day to get Monday, but change locale week start with the Monday, so there is no need add an extra day

```
    if(time_to_exe == 6)
    {
var orderDateTime = moment();
// Get Sunday (first day) of this week and add 3 days (to get to Wednesday) and set the time to 11:59am
var cutOffDate = moment().startOf('week').add(2,'days').set({'hour': 11, 'minute': 59, 'second': 59});
// Initialize delivery date from order date
var deliveryDate = orderDateTime.clone();
if (orderDateTime.isSameOrBefore(cutOffDate)) {
    deliveryDate = deliveryDate.add(1,'week').startOf('week'); // Monday next week
} else {
    deliveryDate = deliveryDate.add(2,'week').startOf('week'); // Monday the week after next
}
    
    if (deliveryDate) {
  time_to_exe = deliveryDate.format("D. MMMM");
      
    } else {
      time_to_exe = time_to_exe + "d";
    }
    }
```